# Shuffle an array in Node.js with some rules

Tags: arrays, node.js, node-modules

I tried to shuffle an array and i made it with this code:

```
var array = [ 'num1', 'num2', 'num3', 'num4', 'num5', 'num6' , 'num7', 'num8', 'num9' , 'num10', 'num11', 'num12'  ];

array = shuffle(array);

function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}
```

However, instead of just shuffling the array, I want the algorithm to respect these rules:

I have to create a table shuffling this array, for example:

```
PART1  |   PART2   |   PART3
numX        numX        numX
numX        numX        numX
numX        numX        numX
numX        numX        numX
```

where numX is a number in the array.

RULES TO RESPECT:

- Columns number is variable from 1 to X
- On every row I can't have the same number
- Every number must be in every column only ones (in random position)
- I can't have a number next to the same number on the columns (at least with 1 number of space beetwen each other)

EXAMPLE TABLE

```
PART1  |   PART2   |   PART3
num1        num2        num3
num4        num5        num6
num2        num3        num1
num5        num6        num4
num3        num1        num2
num6        num4        num5
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple (but inelegant) solution would be to just shuffle until an output matching the rules is found:

```js
var array = [ 'num1', 'num2', 'num3', 'num4', 'num5', 'num6' , 'num7', 'num8', 'num9'];
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}

const numParts = 9;
const itemsInPositions = Array.from(
  { length: array.length },
  () => []
);

const parts = Array.from(
  { length: numParts },
  () => {
    let shuffled;
    do {
      shuffled = shuffle(array.slice());
    } while (shuffled.some((item, i) => itemsInPositions[i].includes(item)));
    shuffled.forEach((item, i) => {
      itemsInPositions[i].push(item);
      // reset to length 2:
      itemsInPositions[i] = itemsInPositions[i].slice(-2);
    });
    return shuffled;
  }
);
document.write(parts.join('<br>'));
```

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance and thanks for your help, your solution is partly ok, i need to have the number of columns variable and i have to respect the last rule (I can't have a number next to the same number on the columns (at least with 1 number of space beetwen each other)

Comment: You can change the number of columns/parts by changing the `numParts` variable. The `itemsInPositions` array keeps the last couple items in state for each row to ensure that repeats don't occur.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried to change the numParts variable, however the result in console is still composed of 9 columns, and in this case 3 rows instead of 9 like in the old test. @CertainPerformance

Comment: Each `parts` subarray has 9 elements because the `array` variable at the very top has 9 elements (like like your original array had 12 elements). If you want to change that, then just put a different number of items into it.